# Bandwidth monitoring on KVM

Tags: networking, ubuntu-10.04, kvm-virtualization, bandwidth-control, libvirt

Is it possible to monitor/limit bandwidth for KVM guests? I'd like to give people VMs on my server but I want to be careful not to go over my monthly bandwidth limit. The only places I can find that support this are 'cloud' frameworks, I'm guessing I'm either missing something simple in Linux, or I need to talk to a router above me (which I don't have access to).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recommend using [**libvirt**](http://libvirt.org/) for managing your KVM virtual machines. It makes the whole thing much easier than with just plain QEMU/KVM and provides also nice CPU, IO and **network statistics**. You will like tools such as **virt-top** and **virt-manager** which work on top of the *libvirt* framework.

To collect the virtual machine interface statistics from a script, you could use **virsh** command line interface to *libvirt* or some of the language APIs. The format of the *virsh* command is as follows:

```
virsh domifstat VMNAME IFNAME
```

..where VMNAME is the name of your virtual machine and IFNAME is the name of a (virtual) network interface. To find out a name of a network interface you can do:

```
virsh dumpxml VMNAME
```

In the resulting XML output, look for your network interface definition(s). Look for a line such as follows:

```
<target dev='vnet0'/>
```

In this case your IFNAME would be "vnet0".

Alternatively you could use a statistics collection daemon, such as *collectd* which has support for monitoring *libvirt* statistics, but a simple shell script which some times stores the output of "virsh domifstat" is maybe enough in this case.

Comment: I do use libvirt. Where do I find network statistics? I'm not installing virt-manager, it wants to install Gnome.

Comment: I edited the answer to include further practical information for retrieving libvirt interface statistics with virsh command line tool. Also note that you do not need to install virt-manager on the VM host. You can install it in your workstation and instruct it to connect to a remote VM host (or several). Thus no need for Gnome/X11 libraries on the VM host.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Given the general lack of information like this on the net (or just the difficulty finding it), you'd think that 99% of the people using KVM don't have customers. :-P

Comment: That is a strange distro that requires gnome for virt-manager. Debian just wants gconf2 - the rest seem like Python libraries.

Comment: I found it useful to use a modified command from this answer to find the interface. `virsh dumpxml VMNAME | grep "target dev"`